# Dataframe Left Merge with Matching Keys In Different Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have to merge two `DataFrame`, with a Left Join - Illustration below.

Problem is that the matching key is spread across 3 columns. To further complicate the challenge, some rows (#4) will have the same matching key twice! I was advised to use `Melt` but it only work for a Right Join.

What is the best approach?

import pandas as pd

```
data1 = {'key1' : ['abc','aa','aa','sdf'],
         'key2' : ['aa','efg','aa', 'sdf'],
         'key3' : ['aa','aa','xyz', 'aa']
        }

data2 = {'key': ['abc','efg', 'xyz', 'sdf'], 
        'msg' : ['happy','mad','smile','great']}

df1= pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2= pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `stack` to reshape `df1` then `map` the keys with the corresponding `msg` from `df2`, finally `groupby` on `level=0` and aggregate using `first`:

```
df1['msg'] = df1.stack().map(df2.set_index('key')['msg']).groupby(level=0).first()
```

---

```
  key1 key2 key3    msg
0  abc   aa   aa  happy
1   aa  efg   aa    mad
2   aa   aa  xyz  smile
3  sdf  sdf   aa  great
```

Comment: Works perfectly! May I ask if there is any limitations to this method?

Comment: What if DF1 has the 3 key but also non-key columns. How may I apply stack? @shubham-sharma

Comment: @denpy That's great! I don't think there are any limitations except when `df2` contains duplicate keys..But in that case you can use `drop_duplicates` and this will work fine.

Comment: @denpy In case the dataframe contains non-key columns you can simply filter the required `key` columns using `df1.filter(like='key')` before using `stack`

Comment: @denpy Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this ? You can recreate a temporary dataframe where all keys are on the same columns, make your join, then drop any duplicates (and re-merge to your first dataframe) :

```
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(
  df1[["index", "key1"]].values.tolist()
  + df1[["index", "key2"]].values.tolist()
  + df1[["index", "key3"]].values.tolist(),
  columns=['index', 'key'])
df4 = df3.merge(df2, on="key", how="left")
df4.sort_values('index', inplace=True)
df4.drop_duplicates('index', keep='first')

df = df1.merge(df4[['index', 'msg']], on="index", how='left')
```